# How long does it take to compile gcc 7.3.0?

Tags: gcc

So far it's been running for about 4 hours. One thing to note is that I did not have the prerequisites and had to download them though contrib/download_prerequisites. Not sure if it adds to the compile time or not.

Machine specs listed below:

```
4 CPUs Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 0 @ 2.00GHz

uname -a
Linux <name> 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 25 13:49:55 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


free -m
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          11854         676        1040           8       10137       
10821
Swap:          5119           0        5119
```

Comment: It depends on your CPU, disk, configured languages, configured targets, whether you’re building with LTO, whether you’re running the tests...

Comment: Updated the question with the CPU info and some additional information about the prerequisites.

Comment: Here are the exact steps I did 1) contrib/download_prerequisites 2) configure 3) make

Comment: On my SPARC T3 with `gmake -j` it took a few hours. On my Powerbook G4 it took a couple days. Having to compile additional things (GMP, ISL, etc) will certainly add to the compile time, but how much is uncertain. If you think GCC is slow to build, you should try **GHC**

Comment: On my Acer E15 (Intel Core i3, 4 GB RAM) it took about 2.5 hours to build gcc (using make -j4)

Comment: on my ubuntu 18.04 system (which notably simlinks /bin/sh to dash and not bash), with a Ryzen 2600 and  `make -j 12`, building gcc took exactly 31 minutes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

After about 4.5 hours it finished.

P.S. Not sure why this question deserved a negative rating. Hopefully it will still help some folks, should they find their compile time take excessively long.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this.  It's very useful to have a reference!

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the solution to your question to pass the message that your query was answered :)

Comment: Mine takes 4 hours and 20 minutes, single thread (with 16 concurrent compiling tasks) Ryzen 7 1800X.

Comment: Hi, do you remember how long it took to download the prerequisites? I ran `./contrib/download_prerequisites` but there is no output and neither is it exiting. It just seems to be stuck. How do I know if things are even getting downloaded? I'm working behind a proxy so I'm not sure.

Comment: Helpful to see this while waiting for libgcc7 to compile on an old PowerPC Mac mini, which took about 13 hours!

Comment: I just compiled gcc-13.1.0. It took 6 hours and 40 minutes.

Comment: @momo check if any files are downloaded in the working directory